# Visual Studio 2015 and Team Foundation 2017

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

Is it possible to use Visual Studio 2015 with Team Foundation 2017.

I'm asking because if I create a new Team Project from visual studio I get the following error:

```
TF400324: Team Foundation services are not available from the server. 
Technical information (for administrator):
TF200038: You cannot create a team project with your version of Team Explorer. Contact your system administrator to determine how to upgrade your Team Explorer client to the version compatible with Team Foundation Server.
```

According to this
[article](https://tfs.discountasp.net/kb/a1378/project-creation-errors-tf400324-and-tf200038.aspx) , with Team foundation 2015 you should use at least VS 2015.
If the logic is the same I would say that I cannot use TF2017 with VS 2015.

Can anyone confirm me this or tell me that I'm wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Team Explorer in Visual Studio is generally compatible with newer versions of Team Foundation Server, but with some exceptions.

You can see the details specified by Microsoft here: [Requirements and compatibility](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/requirements). Under *Client compatibility* they have the following statement:

> Only the latest version has "full" compatibility with the latest Team Foundation Server, because this will be the only client that contains components that can interface with new features for that release, and will also be the only client from which you can perform certain administrative tasks such as creating new team projects.

You can however use the web interface for most administration operations.